# pthread_mutex_lock() and EnterCriticalSection

Tags: winapi, pthreads, mutex

may be I misunderstood something but...

When I call pthread_mutex_lock() and then call pthread_mutex_lock() out of the *same* thread again without calling pthread_mutex_unlock(), the second call of pthread_mutex_lock() will block.

But: when I call EnterCriticalSection() and call EnterCriticalSection() out of the *same* thread again without calling LeaveCriticalSection(), the second call of EnterCriticalSection() will NOT block since it is called out of the same thread (what is a very weird behaviour for me).

So my question is there a WinAPI function available that behaves like pthread_mutex_lock() and locks independent from the thread context?

I'm aware of libpthread for Windows but I prefer to have a WinAPI function here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Semaphore with the maximum count set to one.
See [Semaphore Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685129.aspx)

When you successfully acquire the semaphore, its count is decremented: going to zero in our case.
No other thread can acquire it, including the current one.

Comment: Nevertheless thanks! Your answer confirms my solution is working :-)

Answer (score 0):

pthread_mutex_lock documentation:

`If the mutex type is PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE, then the mutex maintains the concept of a lock count. When a thread successfully acquires a mutex for the first time, the lock count is set to one. Every time a thread relocks this mutex, the lock count is incremented by one. Each time the thread unlocks the mutex, the lock count is decremented by one. When the lock count reaches zero, the mutex becomes available for other threads to acquire. If a thread attempts to unlock a mutex that it has not locked or a mutex which is unlocked, an error will be returned.`

MSDN [ReleaseMutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states:

`A thread can specify a mutex that it already owns in a call to one of the wait functions without blocking its execution. This prevents a thread from deadlocking itself while waiting for a mutex that it already owns. However, to release its ownership, the thread must call ReleaseMutex one time for each time that it obtained ownership (either through CreateMutex or a wait function).`

The [wait functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#single-objectwaitfunctions) are the equivalent to pthread_mutex_lock.

See [Mutex Objects (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get more details about this API.

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342025/what-does-the-win32-critical-section-contain) stackoverflow entry to see what the CRITICAL_SECTION object contains. This will disclose
that the CRITICAL_SECTION object holds - among others - a value `LockCount` to allow recursive use. See the [EnterCriticalSection function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to learn about this feature.

Comment: OK, but this isn't an answer to my question how such a thread-independent lock can be done with WINAPI...

Comment: FYI: I added the Windows API hint and links

Comment: The Windows Mutex does the same crap: it does not lock for mutliple locks out of the same thread. It seems like CreateSemaphore() and ReleaseSemaphore() with a lock count of 1 does the job independent from the callings thread context...

Comment: May I ask a question back? What would be the purpose of locking the **same** lock from within one thread multiple times?

Comment: To have full compatibility with libpthreads - which is important within a cross-platform environment. And to have the same bugs on all used platforms and not a different behaviour.