# C# marshalling for HANDLE and CRITICAL_SECTION

Tags: c#, c, marshalling

I am developing a C# (.NET Core) application, and I need to call a C function from an external library.

But I am having trouble when marshaling `thread_t` and `lock_t`.

This is the C code:

```
EXPORT void strsvrinit (strsvr_t *svr, int nout);

typedef struct {        /* stream server type */
    int state;          /* server state (0:stop,1:running) */
    ...
    thread_t thread;    /* server thread */
    lock_t lock;        /* lock flag */
} strsvr_t;

#ifdef WIN32
#define thread_t    HANDLE
#define lock_t      CRITICAL_SECTION
#else
#define thread_t    pthread_t
#define lock_t      pthread_mutex_t
#endif
```

How can I implement marshaling for `thread_t` (`HANDLE`) and `lock_t` (`CRITICAL_SECTION`)?

Comment: `HANDLE` would be a pointer (i.e. `IntPtr`), `CRITICAL_SECTION` is a [struct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2342094/69809). Are you sure it isn't a [`LPCRITICAL_SECTION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-initializecriticalsection)? If it's a struct, you will have to [p/invoke it too](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures.CRITICAL_SECTION).

Comment: CRITICAL_SECTION objects may not be moved or copied, so marshaling it would be a bad idea (since that's a copy).

Comment: @RaymondChen: if the function is p/invoked with a `ref` parameter, it should be functionally equivalent to passing a pointer to the struct, which is done when calling `InitializeCriticalSection` or `EnterCriticalSection` anyway.

Comment: @Groo True, but in that case you're not marshaling the `CRITICAL_SECTION`. You're just passing a reference. And you'll have to pin the `CRITICAL_SECTION` to prevent its address from changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a `HANDLE` is a `*void` in C/C++, in C# it is a `IntPtr`.

`CRITICAL_SECTION` is a structure:

```
typedef RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION CRITICAL_SECTION;

typedef struct _RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION {
    PRTL_CRITICAL_SECTION_DEBUG DebugInfo;
    LONG LockCount;
    LONG RecursionCount;
    HANDLE OwningThread; 
    HANDLE LockSemaphore;
    ULONG_PTR SpinCount;
} RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION, *PRTL_CRITICAL_SECTION;
```

in C# code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CRITICAL_SECTION {
    public IntPtr DebugInfo;
    public int LockCount;
    public int RecursionCount;
    public IntPtr OwningThread;
    public IntPtr LockSemaphore;
    public UIntPtr SpinCount;
}
```

Answered by t3f

Answer (score 1):

How about just referencing them with `IntPtr`? I assume you are not going to modify these structures from the C# code, or even try to pass them by value to the C code (bad idea) but to pass their pointer to a P/Invoked function.

So just reference them as `IntPtr`, which is equivalent to basically `void*`

Comment: With `#define lock_t CRITICAL_SECTION`, it would appear that `lock_t` is a struct, not a pointer.

Comment: yeah, but I really doubt that something like a lock type will be passed by value.